# Azure data factory data flow json to SQL

Tags: sql, json, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I have a source JSON file with hierarchical data, which I need to sink in two SQL tables(relational).
The JSON is as below

```
{
"orders":[
  {
    "orderid":"30933",
    "ordername":"abc",
    "items":[
      {
        "itemid":1,
        "itemstatus":"Failed"
      },
      {
        "itemid":2,
        "itemstatus":"Failed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderid":"308320",
    "ordername":"xyz",
    "items":[
      {
        "itemid":5,
        "itemstatus":"Succeeded"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

My SQL holding two tables Order and OrderItem with OrderID primary and foreign key.

Now I have an Azure data factory data flow with source as above JSON and I need to park all data relational in respective tables.

So here I need OrderId(30933,308320) and OrderName(abc,xyz) will go into Order table and respective items data go into OrderItem table(which reference OrderId from Order table). In this case Order table have 2 and OrderItem table have 3 entries.

Comment: which data to which table,  please clarify it to us?

Comment: @LeonYue I've just updated the question.

Comment: Hi @Manish Jain,  If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. If you have any other concerns, please let us know.

Comment: @LeonYue,Thanks for your time and effort. Sure I'll check it and do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can not achieve that in one copy active.

We could using two copy actives in one pipeline, I tested and it succeed. You could follow my steps bellow:

1. Copy active1: copy the data from `Orders`(orderid and ordername) to table `Orders`.
2. Copy active2: copy the data from `items`(itemid and itemstatus) to
   table `OrderItems`.

**Note:**

1. Copy active 1 and 2 use the same json file as the source. The
   differences are in the Mapping settings.
2. Copy active 1 sink is Azure SQL database table `Orders`, Copy active
   2 sink is Azure SQL database table `OrderItems`.

To make you understand it clearly, I made two GIF pictures.

**Mapping settings in Copy active 1:**
[image]

**Mapping settings in Copy active 2:**
[image]

Run the pipeline:

[image]

Check the data in table:

[image]

The limit is that we only could get the first element of `items`, we can not choose the collection reference both.

[image]

Update:

Congratulations that you achieved it in another way: flatten/transpose the data using data flow and then maintain it to pour in a relational SQL table.

Comment: Hi Actually I achieved it in another way, but as per your knowledge, I would say the answer will productive to others.
I flatten/transpose the data using data flow and then maintain it to pour in a relational SQL table.

Comment: @ManishJain Congratulations! I will update my answer. Thanks for share the workaround for us.